# BigQuery Challenge: How can I correctly assign the value by next available value and keep it until the next update?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Come up with a quite challenging BigQuery question here.
So basically, I have to assign the next available value to **session1**'s **code** (in this case session 1 should be the next available value -> 123.
However, we want to keep the **code** value at 234 in **session4** until it gets another update.

Here's what I have:

| timestamp | session | user_id | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ts1 | 1 | User A | NULL |
| ts2 | 2 | User A | NULL |
| ts3 | 2 | User A | 123 |
| ts4 | 3 | User A | NULL |
| ts5 | 3 | User A | 234 |
| ts6 | 4 | User A | NULL |

And the desired output table:

| timestamp | session | user_id | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ts1 | 1 | User A | 123 |
| ts2 | 2 | User A | 123 |
| ts3 | 2 | User A | 123 |
| ts4 | 3 | User A | 234 |
| ts5 | 3 | User A | 234 |
| ts6 | 4 | User A | 234 |

Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider below approach.

```sql
SELECT *, 
       COALESCE(
         FIRST_VALUE(code IGNORE NULLS) OVER w0,
         LAST_VALUE(code IGNORE NULLS) OVER w1
       ) AS new_code
  FROM sample_table
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY timestamp),
       w0 AS (w RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING),
       w1 AS (w RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW);
```

**Query results**

[image]

Comment: Yes @JayTiger, that's a much clear option than the one I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

JayTiger's answer is a much cleaner, but here's what I came up with that can be used as an alternative:

```sql
SELECT *EXCEPT (Code),
       IFNULL(
               (FIRST_VALUE(LatestCodeBySession IGNORE NULLS)
                            OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY event_timestamp ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)),
               (LAST_VALUE(LatestCodeBySession IGNORE NULLS)
                           OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY event_timestamp ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)))
           AS Code

LatestCodeBySession: `LAST_VALUE(Code IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY session ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)`
```